# UILabel sizeToFit crashing in iOS 8

Tags: ios, crash, uilabel, drawrect, sizetofit

I have a very strange problem since I updated iPad on iOS 8.1.3.
Anywhere in the app where some label needs to go with multiline (numberOfLines set on 0) it crashes on when drawing rect or on sizeToFit.

This was working just fine on iOS7.

Here is call stack when crash happens: http://s16.postimg.org/txnmngglh/Screen_Shot_2015_02_09_at_11_01_41_AM.png

Answer (score 0):

Just Uncheck Autolayout & try again.

If you don't want to Uncheck Autolayout than simply add this line:

```
Your_TextView.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. When numberOfLines = 0 app crashes. Without this it works but I don't have multiline.